# ArcPy cartography.ConvertLabelsToGraphics runs in the Python window in ArcGIS Pro, but fails to run from script/ToolBox

Tags: arcgis-pro, cartographic-information-model

I am trying to run the code below to convert labels into Graphics. The code works fine when I run it in the Python window in ArcGIS Pro 3.1.0. However, when I place it the same code that create the layers in a script attached to a toolbox, I am getting the following errors message:

> Invalid CIM dataset for path:
> CIMPATH=Layers/4184543cb62240c0aea2bbf2424363cd.json Failed to execute
> (ConvertLabelsToGraphics).

```py
project = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("current")
for mp in project.listMaps():
    print("Converting labels to graphics for: " + mp.name)
    arcpy.cartography.ConvertLabelsToGraphics(
            mp, 2350626, 'ALL_LAYERS', '', 'Graphics_' + mp.name, 'MAXOF', 
            'GRAPHICS_LAYER_PER_FEATURE_LAYER', 'ONLY_PLACED',  
            'GraphicsLayers_' + mp.name)
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. This is an example of a "Wall of code" post (though it's a short wall, more like a hedge). All Questions should have a paragraph or three describing the environment and task, along with a description of the problem (e.g., what the exact failure message states, as text in the body of the Question). It is often best to write the entire Question, then compose a title which summarizes it, rather than put all the text in the title.

Comment: The error message would suggest one of your layers in an issue. I would try running your code in a new map with a single layer to test if it is the data or you have invalid syntax in your code?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I did exactly what you said but I am getting the same error. However, when I run the code in the python widow in ArcGIS Pro, it works fine, no errors.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of ArcPro?

Comment: Yes, ArcGIS Pro 3.1